# Disable mouse pointer but read the mouse events

Tags: mouse, input, xinput

There are similar questions on this site, but my scenario is bit different.

I have an additional mouse; lets call it X. I use a python script to read X movement (read `/dev/input/mouse1`) which I use to control an embedded device. However I do not want the pointer to move when X moves.

Is there a way to disable only the mouse pointer and not its events?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xinput` to remove your mouse from the `Virtual core pointer`. In that way the mouse cursor ("
core pointer") won't be controlled any longer by it, and the core protocol won't produce any mouse events.

You can still receive the mouse events either on the input layer, as you are already doing (via `/dev/input`). Note that this is *not* X movement, but one layer below (before `evdev` or similar X drivers process it).

Or you can receive X input events for the detached mouse using the `XINPUT` X extension. See `xinput --test` and `xinput --test-xi2` for an example program that does that.